# unable to execute ansible play on remote host

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run multiple shell commands in ansible on a remote host, but failing miserably:

```
   - name: Mkdir on server and copy packages locally
     shell: |
      mkdir /root/vdbench
      cd /root
      cp vdbench50403.zip /root/vdbench
      cd /root/vdbench
      unzip vdbench50403.zip
```

Error:

```
TASK [Mkdir on server and copy packages locally] *******************************
fatal: [153.254.108.166]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mkdir /root/vdbench\n cd /root\n cp vdbench50403.zip /root/vdbench\n cd /root/vdbench\n unzip vdbench50403.zip", "delta": "0:00:00.006011", "end": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.518445", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.512434", "stderr": "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/vdbench’: File exists\n/bin/sh: line 4: unzip: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": ["Consider using file module with state=directory rather than running mkdir"]}
fatal: [153.254.108.165]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mkdir /root/vdbench\n cd /root\n cp vdbench50403.zip /root/vdbench\n cd /root/vdbench\n unzip vdbench50403.zip", "delta": "0:00:00.005799", "end": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.740551", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.734752", "stderr": "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/vdbench’: File exists\n/bin/sh: line 4: unzip: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": ["Consider using file module with state=directory rather than running mkdir"]}
fatal: [153.254.108.164]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mkdir /root/vdbench\n cd /root\n cp vdbench50403.zip /root/vdbench\n cd /root/vdbench\n unzip vdbench50403.zip", "delta": "0:00:00.006032", "end": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.745565", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.739533", "stderr": "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/vdbench’: File exists\n/bin/sh: line 4: unzip: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": ["Consider using file module with state=directory rather than running mkdir"]}
fatal: [153.254.108.163]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "mkdir /root/vdbench\n cd /root\n cp vdbench50403.zip /root/vdbench\n cd /root/vdbench\n unzip vdbench50403.zip", "delta": "0:00:00.006703", "end": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.832733", "failed": true, "rc": 127, "start": "2017-05-26 07:24:30.826030", "stderr": "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/vdbench’: File exists\n/bin/sh: line 4: unzip: command not found", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": ["Consider using file module with state=directory rather than running mkdir"]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Read what the output is telling you:

- mkdir fails because the directory already exists
- The target systems lack the unzip command.

To fix the errors do the following:

- pass the -p flag to mkdir
- install unzip on the destination server

Or, much better yet, change your playbook to do things with ansible modules as opposed to just running shell commands on the targets hosts.

```
- name: Extract vdbench
  unarchive:
    src: vdbench50403.zip
    dest: /root/vdbench
```

Note that src is a file on the computer you are running ansible on.

Comment: Great advice for using zip module,, one more thing while using shell module how can i run 2 cmds together like

`mkdir /root/test1
mkdir /root/test2`

Comment: `shell: mkdir /root/test{1,2}`
OR
`shell: mkdir /root/test1; mkdir /root/test2`